# Como concatenar parentesis de inicio y cierre en java sobre variables especificas en cadenas de texto?

Tags: java, string, arraylist

A partir de la siguiente cadena de texto o formula:

```
  cadena="(H100B) * (H200B) + H310B + H330B + H100C + H200C + H310C + H330C";
```

Quiero concatenar un parentesis de inicio "(" y un parentesis de cierre")" en las variables: `H100B, H200B, H310B,H330B,H100C,H200C,H310C` por ejemplo `(H100B)`
Por lo que el resultado final quedaría como:

```
  "((H100B)) * ((H200B)) + (H310B) + (H330B) + (H100C) + (H200C) + (H310C) + (H330C)";
```

Respetando siempre los operadores y parentesis de la cadena original.

tengo algo como esto en java:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.*;

public class Prueba{

   public static void main(String args[]){
       String cadena="(H100B) * (H200B) + H310B + H330B + H100C + H200C + 
       H310C + H330C";
       String resultado=aplicar_formato(cadena);
   }

   String cadena="(H100B) * (H200B) + H310B + H330B + H100C + H200C + H310C + H330C";

    public static String aplicar_formato(String cadena){   

        StringBuilder resultado=new StringBuilder(cadena);

        System.out.println(resultado);

        char[] caracteres=cadena.toCharArray();

        String cadena_variables;
        String cadena_restantes;

        StringBuffer cadenafinal=new StringBuffer(cadena);
        ArrayList<Integer> posiciones=new ArrayList<Integer>();
        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder(); 

        for (int i = 0; i < caracteres.length; i++) {

            if(Character.isLetter(caracteres[i])){              
                posiciones.add(i);
                ar.add(caracteres[i]);
            }
        }

        System.out.println(cadena);


        System.out.println("posiciones de variables: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < posiciones.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(i);

            if(i%2==0){
                resultado.setCharAt(posiciones.get(i), '(');
            }else{
                resultado.setCharAt(posiciones.get(i), ')');
            }

          return resultado.toString();
        }

}
```

Pero al imprimir el resultado, lo muestra como:

```
((100)) * ((200)) + (310) + (330) + (100C) + (200) + (310) + (330)
```

en vez de mostrar el siguiente resultado:

```
((H100B)) * ((H200B)) + (H310B) + (H330B) + (H100C) + (H200C) + (H310C) + (H330C)"
```

¿Como podría realizar esta concatenación sin que se reemplacen los elementos por el indice?

Comment: Si te refieres al escape de caracteres tan solo sería :  "\"Hola mundo\" " y como resultado te mostrara "Hola mundo"

Comment: no, no me refiero a eso, sino que quiero concatenar un parentesis de inicio "(" y de cierre ")" en las variables que se encuentran en la cadena original, pero sin que se modifiquen los caracteres originales de la cadena.

Comment: no se reemplaza nada, estas perdiendo caracteres...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te dejo el código en javascript (para que tomes la idea para java) para que te sirva de ayuda yo lo que haría seria tokenizar el string ya que parece que siempre esta separado por espacios y detectar cuales de esos son operaciones y trabajar con los otros resultados un ejemplo sencillo seria

```js
var cadena="(H100B) * (H200B) + H310B + H330B + H100C + H200C + H310C + H330C";
console.log('cadena original  ->>'+cadena);
var spliter= cadena.split(' ');//spit por espacios
var result ='';
spliter.forEach(x => {//bucle foreach para recorrer el array que monta
if(!x.includes('+')&&!x.includes('*')&&!x.includes('-')&&!x.includes('/')){//condicion
result=result+' ('+x+') ';
}else{result=result+x}
})
console.log('resultado --> '+result);
```

Comment: muchas gracias @Erique Asensio, realmente me funciono